# C# UTF8 console output

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm trying to make something like http://www.a1k0n.net/2011/07/20/donut-math.html but with unicode characters.

To achieve this, I'd originally tried to alter the encoding of the console. However, there don't seem to be any console fonts that support the characters I'd like to use. Does anyone know:

- How I can change the font used by the console to one that supports unicode characters, such as Arial?
- Whether this is a good solution to the problem, rather than (say) using a text box in a windows form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest changing the font on a console window. It's not designed to be that type of user interface. Any power user will get mad if your application changes their command prompt outside of the application. If you want 'pretty' then I would suggest a Winform. Otherwise I think you are opening a Pandora's box.

IF you insist then I would suggest checking out Console.InputEncoding and to change font in the console you will need to access the kernel itself... not suggested solution.. this article has the details on the implementation http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/

Comment: I figured it might be a bad idea, thanks for the advice. I'll try to make my own text-based GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt). But it will work only on your pc.